# How to set up authentication on @AutoConfigureStubRunner?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

How to set up authentication on the @AutoConfigureStubRunner annotation in Spring Cloud Contract?

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
    stubsMode = REMOTE,
    ids = ["some-stub-id"],
    repositoryRoot = "https://jfrog.myrepo.com/artifactory/public-maven"
)
```

Is there any way to pass on the username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the username and password can be set in the application.properties file like this:

```
stubrunner.username=<username>
stubrunner.password=<password>
```